Which table engine choose for data update and avoid duplicates in Clickhouse?
I got database, where I need update values in come cases.
For example I got records table.
It contains information about sessions in beauty salon.
Then clients get booked, I add new record with visit_id, client_id, visit date, status of visit (waiting for client, visit canceled, visit confirmed, visit finished), paid (paid - True, not paid - False), shedule_id (schedule contains staff information), etc.
I should update this table every 15 minutes. Information from this table will be instantly goes to Superset dashboard.
Every update includes new visits and update information about visits (changed status, paid, comment, schedule_id).
So I can't decide witch engine will work better for this table ReplacingMergeTree or CollapsingMergeTree.
I think I should use CollapsingMergeTree, cause I need get actual info without any delay.
But I can't get one moment. I must add sing "+1" for new columns and "-1" for old manually.
In my case I get information from API, so I get only actual values. Old values are located only in database.
So I think I need get previous record from database and insert it with sign "-1" manually.
So I stuck at this moment.
Using ReplacingMergeTree engine is not guarantee of drop duplicates.
CollapsingMergeTree - I need add sign to separate old and new version of record, so it's tooks more time to add records with sign "-1".
Which engine be better for my case?
P. S. Table contain not much data for now about 30 000 rows, but with time there will be more records to update.
CREATE TABLE do_you_database.records
(
    record_id UInt32,
    plan_id Nullable(UInt64),
    schedule_id Nullable(UInt64),
    client_id UInt32,
    visit_id UInt32,
    visit_date Nullable(DateTime),
    status Int8,
    visit_duration UInt32,
    paid bool,
    comment Nullable(String),
    source Nullable(String),
    create_date DateTime,
    user_id UInt32,
    PRIMARY KEY (record_id)
)
ENGINE = ***


Some of your comments are misleading, so I want to clarify a few things...

I think I should use CollapsingMergeTree, cause I need get actual info without any delay.

You are implying that ReplacingMergeTree has a delay but CollapsingMergeTree does not, but they both work the same way. There is no "delay" for either table engine if you add FINAL to your queries.

So I think I need get previous record from database and insert it with sign "-1" manually.

You do not need the old values to delete an existing row from a CollapsingMergeTree table - you only need the values of the primary key (more specifically, the sort order key if it's different than the primary key). Just  INSERT a new row with the primary key plus a -1 for the sign column and the previous row will be canceled.

Using ReplacingMergeTree engine is not guarantee of drop duplicates.

Yes it does - it's exactly why it is called "replacing" merge tree: the last row inserted for a specific primary key "replaces" the previous row for that key.

Which engine be better for my case?

Look at it this way: ReplacingMergeTree works great for upserts. A newly inserted row is either simply inserted, or it replaces any existing row with the same key.
CollapsingMergeTree can also implement upsert behavior, but you can also delete rows by passing in a -1 for the sign column.
I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are doing just upserts than use ReplacingMergeTree, and if you are doing upserts and deletes then use CollapsingMergeTree.

"if you are doing just upserts than use ReplacingMergeTree". Thanks.
